# Materialize nav content won't center ul element

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, materialize, nav

I'm trying to center nav-content using center option

[So it will look like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aM8EZ.png)

However it doesn't work on the ul attribute.

[Ends up looking like this instead.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45bIo.png)

My code:

```
...
        <div class="nav-content center" style="background-color: black">
            <ul class="tabs tabs-transparent">
                <li class="tab"><a href="">Test 1</a></li>
                <li class="tab"><a href="">Test 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Solution:

mdubus' answer is correct but it needs to be in the ul element instead of the div for it to work using Materialize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your div `nav-content center`, just add a `display:flex; justify-content:center;`. That should do the trick ;)

Comment: Like this?
`<div class="nav-content" style="background-color: black; display:flex; justify-content:center;">`

Didn't seem to do anything...

Comment: It works for me : 
https://codepen.io/mdubus/pen/YdmoMP

Isn't that what you want ?


Edit: I added the inline-style as it fits what you want, and removed the background-color for more visibility

Comment: Was able to make it work by placing it in the ul element. I guess Materialize still overwrites it if it is placed in the div element.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familliar with materielize, you can do it with css, by stting the parent element to: `flex` and justifiy-content: center; or simply by setting .nav-content{ text-align: center; }